# How to monitor docker daemon pull progress

Tags: docker

`docker pull ...` gives nice progress bars. However, there are several occasions where these progress bars are not supplied. E.g.

- `docker pull` on an image that is already being pulled (even though you maybe tried to cancel the earlier pull); this is also an active issue: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8385
- `fig pull`, where you get only one log statement per docker image defined in your fig configuration

These are all issues where it might be the responsibility of the specific use case to supply insight to the progress, but in case they do not, it would be nice to be able to do the monitoring in a different way. So the question is: *"How do I monitor progress of a running docker pull process?"* To make it easy, let's assume full docker host access (local development).

Answer (score 0):

Nethogs seems to do what you want, as I guess docker will use a lot of bandwith, see https://github.com/raboof/nethogs, for example, if you have a wlan0 interface, you will launch `sudo nethogs wlan0`

Comment: you can also use nethogs in a container of course https://hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/nethogs/ :-)